# Detect keypress but only once. Keyboard module isn't working this way

Tags: python, keypress

I want to detect a keypress and when it happands i want to do something once. If i use the keyboard module for this it does te statement a few times.

I have tried other modules but i can't figure it out.

```
import turtle
import keyboard

count_a = 5

#screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#pen
pen= turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.write(count_a, align="center", font=("courier", 24, "normal"))

#main
while True:
    wn.update()

    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        count_a -= 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write(count_a, align="center", font=("courier", 24, "normal"))
```

If you press "a" in my program the count goes a lot lower then -1. I just wnt the count to be 4 if you've pressed it once.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want to **stop** the loop from running after a press occurs, you may want to add `break`:

```py
while True:
    wn.update()

    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        count_a -= 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write(count_a, align="center", font=("courier", 24, "normal"))
        
        break # <-
```

Though, this will **stop** the loop. Although, if you want it to stop your code from executing inside the `if` loop and only have one run of the statement, you could add a flag that stops after it is pressed the first time.

#### If you want to stop your code from executing after the first run of `if`

```py
#main
waitingForA = True
while True:
    wn.update()

    if keyboard.is_pressed('a') and waitingForA: # <-
        count_a -= 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write(count_a, align="center", font=("courier", 24, "normal"))

        waitingForA = False # <-
```

Notice how I added the `waitForA` variabiel, then set it to `False` after we got our first press, this will then stop the `if` statement from running a second time since our if statement resolves to `True` and `False`, which obviously won't run in an **and** statement.

Comment: Note I've not run this code, nor have I used the library you're speaking of. I'm just using my understanding of loops and looping structures.

Comment: Thanks @VietHTran, I changed the variable name to make it a bit simpler.

Comment: This helps a lot thank you, but how do i set the value of waitingForA back to True to use this again.

Comment: Well, JavaScript does this using keyDown and keyEvents, so maybe check google for something similar for python - I’m not at home at the moment so I can’t do this for you